# Menu button doesn't work (wordpress theme)

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

It is a wordpress site and this is from my style.css :

```
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
.sf-menu li { position: relative }
.sf-menu ul { position: absolute; display: none; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 99; }
.sf-menu > li { float: left }
.sf-menu li:hover > ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover > ul { display: block }
.sf-menu a { display: block; position: relative; }
.sf-menu ul ul { top: 0; left: 100%; }
.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul:after { content: "\f347"; display: inline-block; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font: normal 12px/16px 'dashicons'; vertical-align: top; margin: 5px 0px 0 4px; }
.sf-arrows ul .sf-with-ul:after { content: "\f345"; display: inline-block; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font: normal 12px/22px 'dashicons'; float: right; vertical-align: top; margin: 2px 0 0 4px; }
.sf-arrows ul li > .sf-with-ul:focus:after, .sf-arrows ul li:hover > .sf-with-ul:after, .sf-arrows ul .sfHover > .sf-with-ul:after { border-left-color: white }

.navbar-toggle { display: none; position: absolute; left: auto; top: 5px; padding: 14px 13px;   border-radius: 2px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33); }
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar { display: block; width: 25px; height: 2px; border-radius: 1px; background: #fff; }
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar + .icon-bar { margin-top: 4px }
```

the menu block on the site wont expand.(the menu block only appears when page is in moblie-view mode.)

how should i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

in this cases make sure you have installed the theme correctly.
that was the mistake i've made.